# Apply CSS classes if got hidden-xs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have div element:

```
<div class="...">...</div>
```

So when window will be sized to min width and style `hidden-xs` apply,  I need to add few more classes to my div. 
After window sizing it should be:

```
<div class="... margin-top padding-top">...</div>
```

How to add these condition in to css?
p.s. Maybe it is possible to do directly in html by Angularjs?

Comment: Why not editing directly the `.hidden-xs { ... }` class? For exemple in another CSS file, imported after bootstrap.css

Comment: It's not a bad questions, go easy on the down votes!! He's just new to CSS, so is approaching the problem from the wrong direction

Comment: you have multiple options: 1) create a directive which handles window resize and add/remove the class, 2) you can apply a class permanently and define `@media` query which does the trick depending on the window size. For 2) usually is easier to use SASS as you can reuse the variables defined by bootstrap in order to define your boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't dynamically add/remove classes in CSS.

What you could do is dynamically add/reset styles, with `@media` queries.

Let's say all targeted elements have a class called `.target-el`.
All you have to do is:

- set `.target-el.margin-top` rules for both small and large sizes.
- do the same for `.target-el.padding-top`.
- instead of removing a class, set the rule to `auto, none, 0` according to the default value for that rule.
- I've set the class `.margin-top` along with a target marker class `.target-el` so you could still have your default `.margin-class` working properly elsewhere in your code.

Here's an example:

```css
.target-el {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
}

.target-el.margin-top {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.target-el.padding-top {
    padding-top: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .target-el.margin-top {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .target-el.padding-top {
        padding-top: 5px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="target-el padding-top margin-top"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

From Bootstrap code, the `.hidden-xs` code is the following:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

It uses a [media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to be applied (screen > 767px). Instead of manipulating the DOM with JavaScript, I would suggest to use the same media-query on your classes:

```
<div class="... margin-top padding-top">...</div>
```

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .margin-top { 
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .padding-top { 
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to add custom classes depending on a media query, you can use javascript.
This can be done with [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia), or by using a library like [Enquire.js.](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/)

If you don't want to look for the media query that was specified in the bootstrap framework you could also use an `[attribute*=value]` selector to detect all the classes that contain the "-xs" characters, and depending on that to add custom properties for the rest of classes.

```
div[class*="-xs"].margin_top {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

<div class="hidden-xs margin_top">The first div element.</div>
<div class="visible-xs margin_top">The second div element.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a need for js likely, I would create new css for it:

```
<div class="hidden-xs margin-top-xs padding-top-xs">...</div>
```

use a media query css selector:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .margin-top-xs {
    ...
  }

  .margin-padding-xs {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement it with CSS specificity. Something like either of the following:

```css
#MyDiv1.hidden-xs,
#MyDiv2 .hidden-xs{
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="MyDiv1" class="hidden-xs">
</div>
<div id="MyDiv2">
  <div class="hidden-xs"></div>
</div>
```

stead implement it with CSS 'specificity'. Something like: